'Mice IS the scourge of the fields' <-- Plural noun - is/are - predicate noun
I have a question about verb agreement in sentences with the form:

Plural Noun - BE - Predicate-Noun

Are the following sentences grammatical?

Video games is the way [to go].
Mice is the scourge of fields.
Oats was the food to eat.

Does the subject in this type of example always come first? Or is the right hand noun the subject?

Thanks for the response @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. It was the first sentence that caught my attention and I tried to construct similar examples. I looked through CGEL on this topic and couldn't find anything definite regarding this case except for vague remarks that subject-number agreement is not a grammatical, but a semantic issue, which obviously doesn't help.

Examples 2 and 3 were invented by you, you didn't hear them in the wild so to speak? That would explain why sentence 3 sounds so peculiar and unusual to me, even if it had the plural verb, were, it would sound a bit odd. I guess with context it would make perfect sense. Would you thinking of different foods and beverages that were made from oats, or were you thinking of the grain?

@Mari-LouA I was thinking about the porridge. The word was taken from CGEL and I didn't cross-check the meaning.

Does this answer your question? Subject verb agreement when a plural becomes a singular

@StuartF I don't think so. I'm trying to feel the limits of subject-number agreement in English.

@AlexeyVeleshko if so, then you should simply read the correct answer on this page, which is this one: https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/353085/8369 Please beware of input that is giving you theoretically possible 'grammatically correct' utterances which would only be used in and correct in incredibly obscure situations and are otherwise extremely plain wrong.



Video games is the way to go.
Mice is the scourge of fields.
Oats was the food to eat.


Sentence (1) is borderline. You might well encounter sentences like this. Sentence (2) is ungrammatical. Sentence (3) is fine. In all cases plural are would also be possible (in the case of (2) it's essential).
As often mentioned in serious grammar books, subject-verb agreement is essentially based more on meaning, and less on grammatical (i.e. syntactic) properties or features.
Example (1) is ok, because "video games" stands in for a clause or a broader noun phrase. It means something like "choosing video games" or "the option of video games". Such clauses or noun phrases would, of course, take singular agreement.
Example (3) is grammatical because "oats" is being thought of as a dish (a type of meal). Examples like the following are common in English:

Scambled eggs is my favourite breakfast.
Fish and chips is everybody's favourite seaside takeaway.


Cereal is delicious.... Oats are delicious... Porridge is delicious... Oats are given to horses... Oats are food for horses…

Oats are used for human consumption as oatmeal, including as steel cut oats or rolled oats.  (Wikipedia). It seems to me that the OP's 3rd sentence is not talking about the dish but about the cereal. The Scots don't eat oats for breakfast, they eat porridge. Horses eat oats. It would be like saying "Wheat was the food of rural workers” when instead we mean food products such as bread, pasta, flatbread, pies etc.  all different types of food that are made from wheat.

Is sentence 3 being valid dialect-dependent? I've never heard "oats" being used as the name of a dish in the way that "fish and chips" is. In my mind, oats, plural, are a grain used to make the dish porridge. I suspect, but am not sure, that this is a UK vs US difference - that over in the US, the word "oats" can be used as the name of a dish, but that in British English that I'm used to, it can't be. Nor can I find any such BrE examples with a quick google. But maybe I'm wrong - perhaps it's valid in both dialects and I just happen to have never heard the usage!

@MarkAmery: I agree it’s certainly not common to use “oats” as a dish name — but that sort of dish-naming is common enough, and variable enough between dialects/idiolects, that if I heard the sentence from a native speaker, I wouldn’t be at all surprised or hear it as a speech error, I’d just assume that was how they referred to porridge.

@PLL I mean, I guess I'd figure the same, but I was surprised to read this answer saying this was legit usage. It's not just the singular vs plural thing; the sentence "oats was the food to eat" is strange to my ears in the same kind of way as "flour was the food to eat" would be. To me "oats" on its own (rather than e.g. "rolled oats" or "powdered oats") by default just means entirely raw, unprocessed oats, which aren't yet even really a food, let alone a dish.

Am I alone in feeling that inverting sentence 2 would make it more acceptable (though still awkward)? The scourge of the fields is mice. I doubt I would ever write that myself, but I can see how one could argue that the subject here is the scourge and therefore the singular is acceptable.

"Baked Oats is a viral TikTok recipe that's getting popular because it's an easy, versatile & healthy breakfast with a cake taste and texture!".  But for the OP's sentence to work it would need some additional adjective ('Baked', 'Pickled', 'Green') to be the name of the dish, not just 'Oats'.

For company names, British English uses plural, American and Canadian English uses singular verb forms, that also trips up people sometimes.

Every single example given here is wrong.  Telling an English learner that something that is theoretically grammatically correct because it uses an obscure counting sense is correct is wrong.  Video games are the way. Mice are the scourge. Oats are the food. Scrambled eggs are the favorite. Fish and chips are everyone's favorite.  All five examples given here sound like a non-native speaker.

@terdon In inverting the sentence, you have also swapped the Subject and Object.  The first way around, "Mice (pl)" are being something, and that something is "the Scourge of the Field (sg)".  The other way around, "The Scourge of the Field (sg)" is being something: "Mice (pl)"

@fattie  I somewhat agree, but you go too far. The information here isn't wrong, just inadvisable. When there are two ways to say something with different levels of acceptance, it is best to recommend the more acceptable version. Plus, as you state, with a native speaker, what would normally be considered an error may be seen as deliberate to make a point. But with an ESL speaker, it will be seen as a mistake. This answer would be improved by recommending following the standard, universal rules of subject-verb agreement, while allowing that native speakers may make exceptions.

hi @trlkly .  When I got to your sentence "The information here isn't wrong, just inadvisable..." I was about to gush "That is the clearest and best thing I ever read on here..." Then, I read your next sentence, and I was about to gush, "No, wait - THAT is the clearest and best thing I ever read on here...". Then I read your next sentence pair, and I was about to gush, "HOLD EVERYTHING - THAT is the clearest and best thing I ever read on here...". Then I read your concluding sentence and I was just stunned because your WHOLE POST is the clearest and best thing I have ever read on here.

@Fattie Not every learner is intermediate. OP, rightly asked their question on EL&U but it got shunted over here. They're currently reading Huddleston and Pullum's 2,000-page magisterial grammar tome The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language, with its long convoluted mutli-page discussions of the ins and outs of fused determiner-head NPS, metalinguistic negation and auxiliary-stranding long-distance unbounded dependencies. They are not interested in and don't want to know about basic basic verb agreement. ...

@Fattie  They wanted to know about the ins and outs of exactly what they asked about which is cases where we see plural NP subject taking singular verb agreement, after seeing those discussed in CGEL (which is where the first example hails from). Just about the least helpful thing anyone could do for OP - who is, one assumes a C2/Proficiency-level English speaker  - is tell them that this example which they got from a highly reputable published academic book is ungrammatical. The answer is tailored exactly for the level of this particular OP.

@Araucaria-Nothereanymore. whilst I am thoughtful about all of your excellent points, put it this way: at the least, answers should, let's say, "first and completely clearly" answer the question, "Are the following sentences grammatical?" (ie, by typing the two characters "No") and then, by all means, go on to discussion. Literally millions of pure English learners will read this over the next 10,000 years when you and I are long gone. (Don't even mention the current fad for LLM training.)  To put it extremely bluntly (I'm not being rude, just stating the actual reality, the numerical

@Fattie There are also loads of more straightforward examples where this one came from: "Two miles is not far" or "Twenty pounds is not a lot of money" or "Guts is what's required here" or "Subprime mortages is what he lost his money on" yada yada yada.

reality) literally millions of pure English learners in to the deep future will now run around saying "Oh, it's Video games is the way to go and Mice is the scourge of fields - Araucaria clearly said so and that person was one of the best. most cogent and literate writers around."

You interrupted my comment continuation - tsk  :) :)

I am sorry but again bluntly from now on, the reality of the deathless internet is "Oh, it's Video games is the way to go and Mice is the scourge of fields - Araucaria clearly said so and that person was one of the best, most cogent and literate writers around.".  As I say it's a matter of (let's call it) "presentation clarity". Your answer should begin with huge red letters "Hah hah, that's a big NO, those five are TOTALLY WRONG, DON'T SAY THEM."  And THEN the arcane analysis for experts.  That's my take, I'm afraid.

@Fattie But that's not what I said! What I said was that "Video games is the way to go" is borderline and "Mice is the scourge of the fields" is ungrammatical (but that dishes that are plural can have singular agreement).

BTW this problem CONSTANTLY comes up on the physics site, where leading experts (just as yourself) instantly delve in to (wondrous) subtleties without stating clearly the basic (perfectly true) answer at hand.  Cheers !!!

@Fattie I'll sleep on it. (Have to scram right now.)

(Pardon, I meant 1 and 3. not 1 and 2.  1 is totally wrong and 3 is totally wrong.  1 and 3 can be theoretically correct in bizarre situations.)

I will drink on it - the alcoholic way

YES: Plural Noun - BE - Predicate-Noun, that's right, but see below.
If something is seen as a unit or category, the singular can be used.

Video games is or are the way [to go]. [seen as a category or unit of games]
COMPARE: Video games are expensive. [not a category]
Mice is the scourge of fields. [mistake buzzer. Mice cannot be a unit there].
Oats (not wheat) was the food to eat. [seen as a category, ok]

In English, oats as a cereal is always plural, never singular.
No one eats an oat.
Mice are the scourge of fields. It would be quite difficult to see them as categories. It's like most plural statements: Dogs like bones. mice is plural, so are.
[Actually, field mice are very cute. ha ha]

(*) indeed, I felt bad using "mice are the scum of the Earth" as an example! poor wee things

@Fattie Yes, indeed.

I feel like mice could be a category in some elaborate context. Is my understanding correct that we can substitute rodents for mice to get a grammatically correct rodents is the scourge of fields?

@sukhmel Then, you do this: Mice in that chart is a category. It has to be explicit. rodents is plural, mice are plural. No difference in terms of being plural.

In general, the verb should match the subject. So, for example, "Mice are ...", not "Mice is ..." Even if, as in your examples, there is a predicate nominative that is singular.
The "oats" example is debatable. We often use the word "oats" as an uncountable noun rather than as a true plural. No one says, "I ate 50 oats for breakfast." So "Oats is ..." is fine.
I see another poster says that "video games" is being used as an elided form of a longer subject, like "Playing video games is ..." I'd say, well maybe. Sometimes the only way to make sense of a sentence is to assume that words have been omitted. But it's just not necessary in this case. "Video games are the way to go" makes perfect sense if we understand "video games" to be an ordinary plural. Maybe in some context, where you're listing various forms of entertainment perhaps, it would make sense to assume that words have been left out.


Are the following sentences grammatical?

A sentence can be technically grammatically correct because, very simply, all words in English have many, many, different senses and obscure use cases.  The overwhelmingly "normally correct" way to say the example sentences is:

Video games are the way.

Mice are the scum of the Earth.

Oats are the food.

Scrambled eggs are the favorite.

Fish and chips are everyone's favorite.


Of course as with every "what's the way to say this" question on here, you can think of a ridiculously obscure situation where the wrong way, is what would be uttered. Example, some corporate executives discussing how to move forward for maximum profit, "Should we go with video games, designer furniture, or horse vitamin manufacturing?" - "Video games is the way."
The only way a native would utter the five examples is as above. (Except in incredibly obscure situations, and that is true of every utterance and wholly unhelpful when answering an English learner question.)

It's wasn't originally an English learner question though...

To focus first on the word-order question:

the subject is typically before and the object or attribute after the copula, and

all of those can be written inverted, viz.

The way to go is video games.
The scourge of the fields is mice.
The food to eat was oats.



The first part has been covered very well already, but my response is that all are (varying degrees of) acceptable, but I personally would use the plural verb for the second and third. In other words they're not definitively wrong, but they are unusual.

They aren’t. You might, however, rewrite them to use generic singular subjects:

Gaming / A video game is the way to go.


The Mouse is the scourge of fields.


Oatmeal / The Oat was the food of the poor.


It has been suggested that oats cannot be made singular by trimming its s.

@tchrist Some modern examples (from Google nGrams 1957–2019) of “the oat” being used as a singular noun: “The oat was named ‘Carleton’ in 1922 and distributed to growers under that name,” “The oat was produced and seed obtained from the Swedish Plant Breeding Station, at Svälof, Sweden,” “and one-third was planted with oat [...] maize was cultivated after the oat was harvested.”

@tchrist Dictionaries also define oat as a singular noun.
